# Understanding "avoiding sequence"

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

*Each subsequence (91674, 91675, 91672) is called a copy, instance, or occurrence of σ. Since the permutation π = 391867452 contains no increasing subsequence of length four, π avoids 1234.*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_pattern

I'm having trouble understanding what they mean by the last part. What do they mean by "increasing subsequence of length four"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a permutation $\pi$, a permutation pattern contained in it any sequence that can be generated by the following process:

- pick some subsequence of the elements in it,
- relabel them contiguously, keeping the order unchanged.

For example, given the permutation $\pi = 391867452$, there are potentially $\binom{9}{4}$ subsequences of length $4$ that you can pick from it: say, $3918$, or $3164$, or $9752$, etc. (All of these are *subsequences* of $\pi$, meaning that the respective digits are all present in $\pi$, and in exactly that order.)

The permutation pattern associated with each of these is:

- the pattern of $3918$ is $2413$, as you must relabel the smallest number $1$ with the label '1', the second smallest number $3$ with the label '2', the third smallest number $8$ with the label '3', and the largest number $9$ with the label '4'.
- the pattern of $3164$ is $2143$
- the pattern of $9752$ is $4321$.

So we say that $\pi$ contains the *patterns* $2413$, $2143$, $4321$ (and indeed, many others), but $\pi = 391867452$ doesn't contain the pattern $1234$: for that to happen, $\pi$ would have contain as a subsequence, four numbers $a < b < c < d$, but it doesn't. The [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) in $\pi$ is of length $3$ (and there are many such subsequences: $367$, $345$, $167$, $145$, all of which have pattern $123$.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, {3, 9, 1, 8, 6, 7, 4, 5, 2} does not contain a (scattered, not necessarily contiguous) subsequence a < b < c < d (coded as 1234). The longest subsequences are length 3 (coded as 123): 367, 345, 167 and 145.